# Merge Sort adds duplicate data to Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

I'm working with Java to try and sort the price of an object using a Merge Sort. I've already used a merge sort in another piece of code that worked perfectly and I used that model to develop a merge sort for this other project I am working on. However when I run the program It does not output all the items in the Array and ends up duplicating some of the Items.

**TestItem.java**

```
public static void sortPrice(Item[] it, int low, int high) {
    if (low == high) {
        return;
    }
    int middle = (low + high)/2;
    sortPrice(it, low, middle);
    sortPrice(it, middle + 1, high);
    merge(it, low, middle, high);
}

public static void merge(Item[] it, int l, int m, int h) {
    System.out.println(h-l+1);
    Item[] tmpItem = new Item[h - l + 1];
    int index = 0;
    int i = l, j = m + 1;
    while (i <= m || j <= h) {
        System.out.println(m);
        if (i > m) {
            tmpItem[index] = it[j];
            j++;
        } else if (j > h) {
            tmpItem[index] = it[i];
            i++;
        } else if (it[i].getPrice() > it[j].getPrice()) {
            tmpItem[index] = it[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            tmpItem[index] = it[j];
            j++;
        } 
        index++;
    }
    for (int k = l; k <= h; k++) {
        it[k] = it[k - l];
    }
}
```

I want to see an output that looks like this when I run the method `printInventory()` which prints the Array to the Console.

Expected Output (Ordered by Prices from High to Low):

```
1201: Wrench Sets  Quantity Available: 55  Price: $80.0
1500: Ceiling Fans Quantity Available: 100 Price: $59.0   
1034: Door Knobs   Quantity Available: 60  Price: $21.5
1600: Levels       Quantity Available: 80  Price: $19.99
1011: Air Filters  Quantity Available: 200 Price: $10.5
1101: Hammers      Quantity Available: 90  Price: $9.99
```

Actual Output:

```
1201: Wrench Sets  Quantity Available: 55  Price: $80.0
1034: Door Knobs   Quantity Available: 60  Price: $21.5
1600: Levels       Quantity Available: 80  Price: $19.99
1201: Wrench Sets  Quantity Available: 55  Price: $80.0
1034: Door Knobs   Quantity Available: 60  Price: $21.5
1600: Levels       Quantity Available: 80  Price: $19.99
```

Items are declared in **Item.java**

Sorry If I have made and grammatical errors or cause confusion. I am still learning the Java programming language. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code merges from it[] to tempItem[], so that last for loop should copy from tmpItem[] back to it[]:

```
    index = 0;        
    for(i = l; i <= h; i++)
        it[i] = tempItem[index++];
```

Comment: @TimothyRoeJr. - It was a simple mistake. You might want to consider doing a one time allocation of tempItem[] (size = high - low + 1) in the calling code or in a helper function that calls an internal version of merge sort with tempItem[] as a parameter. sortPrice() could be the helper function that allocates tempItem, then use it as a parameter for mergesortPrice(it, low, high, tempItem). Not a big deal for an array this small though.